# show a progress bar from ViewHolder in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I created a recycler view and everything is working fine. there are two buttons in every item in list view. how can i show a loading bar/progress bar on button click event?

I already taken progress bar control in recycler view and i am able to access this on button click event. but progress bar is rendering after button click execution is finished.

here is my axml code:

```html
 <ProgressBar
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circularProgressView" />
```

here is my view holder code:

```
   private void BtnProcessAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //new Activity().RunOnUiThread(() =>
        //{
        //    mProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        //});
        mProgressBar = ItemView.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
        mProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
```

None of them are able to update UI before finished execution.

Comment: find the view before hand and call the progressbar visibility in the first line of button click secondly make the button click event async and add an awaiter and all of it will work just fine

Comment: progress bar visibility code already in first line. but did not try with async await. will try and is there any other event which executed before click in Xamarin.Android? I am trying with touch event though.

Comment: You cannot show it without async await, Secondly when you click on a button the first event that will be called in the page OnTouchEvent for more check overrided method flow cycle

Comment: thanks a ton. it worked like champ. :)

Comment: I Will write it down as an answer and you can mark it right so others can find it? @RaviAnand

Comment: waiting for you answer in down there, thank you.

Comment: I have answered thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is very simple the methods that are containing progress bar are supposed to be asynchronous methods:

```
mProgressBar = ItemView.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
private async void BtnProcessAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    await someMethod(); 
    mProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
```

Also finding id's on button click is a bad practice altogether do it before your button click event make global variables if needed.

Goodluck! 
Happy coding.